# Obfuscate or encrypt Jar library

Tags: java, encryption, jar, locking, obfuscation

i have  a java project that i need to generate a jar from but the jar source code needs to be inaccessible or not readable for the users of the version that uses jars. The idea is to have 2 versions of the framework, but only one version should be allowed to access these files that need to be delivered as jars to the other party.
The rest except those jar parts is identical on both versions

Proguard Obfuscate would be one solution but as i understand it, it changes the variable names only. this is good enough but would then cause problems when we call those methods on common parts as we still have to be able to have the rest code identical as we will work together on it.

Comment: You can't do this reliably. Your best option is to forget about it and use that time for something more constructive.

Comment: I can understand that it cannot be done 100% reliable, but i need to find something as good as possible. Skipping this task is sadly not an option for me. I need to find a way to make the third party not able to reuse and build upon that piece of code, or atleast make it as hard as possible to do so :(

Comment: "code needs to be inaccessible" that also means that the virtual machine will not be able to execute the code,... only option I can think of, is to have the code executed on a server and only send output to user (JSP?)

Comment: Its not that amazing, and its not because i do not want to share it. it is a regular task i got at work, so no, nothing to do with selfishness or similar.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the problem is that the jar needs to be callable withing the project it is included in. Well just the methods from the jar. The logic in the methods has to be unreadable to the human atleast, or just as hard as possible to read

Comment: You can use [yGuard](https://www.yworks.com/products/yguard) which obfuscates variables, method names and classnames. There is an exception list for external visible classes.

Comment: @vanje sounds good, i will give it a try and report back

Comment: All obfuscators have that feature (including Proguard), for obvious reasons.